# How do I make an iTextSharp signature appear on every page of a document?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

when I sign a document the signature only appears on the first page. Is there anything I can do to make it appear on every page? This is the method I'm using right now to sign the PDF, hope it helps find a solution:

```
public static PdfStamper SignHashedUser(string Target, SysX509.X509Certificate2 Certificate, string Reason, string Location, bool AddVisibleSign, PdfReader objReader, int pags)
    {
        X509CertificateParser objCP = new X509CertificateParser();
        X509Certificate[] objChain = new X509Certificate[] { objCP.ReadCertificate(Certificate.RawData) };

        PdfStamper objStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(objReader, new FileStream(Target, FileMode.Create), '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance objSA = objStamper.SignatureAppearance;
        int[] perms = { PdfWriter.AllowPrinting, PdfWriter.AllowFillIn };


        if (AddVisibleSign)
            objSA.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 50, 250, 100), pags, null);
//pags define in which page of the PDF will the signature appear 
        objSA.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
        objSA.SetCrypto(null, objChain, null, null);
        objSA.Acro6Layers = true;
        objSA.Render = PdfSignatureAppearance.SignatureRender.NameAndDescription;
        PdfSignature objSignature = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKMS, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1);
        objSignature.Date = new PdfDate(objSA.SignDate);
        objSignature.Name = PdfPKCS7.GetSubjectFields(objChain[0]).GetField("CN");
        if (objSA.Reason != null)
            objSignature.Reason = objSA.Reason;
        if (objSA.Location != null)
            objSignature.Location = objSA.Location;
        objSA.CryptoDictionary = objSignature;
        int intCSize = 4000;
        Hashtable objTable = new Hashtable();
        objTable[PdfName.CONTENTS] = intCSize * 2 + 2;
        objSA.PreClose(objTable);

        HashAlgorithm objSHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

        Stream objStream = objSA.RangeStream;
        int intRead = 0;
        byte[] bytBuffer = new byte[8192];
        while ((intRead = objStream.Read(bytBuffer, 0, 8192)) > 0)
            objSHA1.TransformBlock(bytBuffer, 0, intRead, bytBuffer, 0);
        objSHA1.TransformFinalBlock(bytBuffer, 0, 0);

        byte[] bytPK = SignMsg(objSHA1.Hash, Certificate, false);
        byte[] bytOut = new byte[intCSize];

        PdfDictionary objDict = new PdfDictionary();

        Array.Copy(bytPK, 0, bytOut, 0, bytPK.Length);

        objDict.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(bytOut).SetHexWriting(true));
        objSA.Close(objDict);

        return objStamper;
    }
```

EDIT: PdfSignatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature() is a method including a parameter indicating the page where the Signature should be displayed. However it can't be used to determine the number of pages where one's signature would be shown..

Comment: if I am not mistaken in the documentation the following is stated 
`signature fields shall never refer to more than one annotation.` have you read or consulted with the documentation also this link may be an alternative - http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2008/04/30/Code-sample-for-using-iTextSharp-PDF-library.aspx

Comment: Didn't help, also I have checked the official itext documentation. And many other sites, all without answers. Anyways thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Technically there's nothing preventing you to have several appearances for the same signature but, and there's always a but, it's not recommended by Adobe and in the next pdf version it will be forbidden explicitly.

Comment: *Is there anything I can do to make it appear on every page* - is it necessary that all those appearances are active elements? Our would out suffice to have multiple visualizations and only one of them being a signature field?

Comment: Well having it visualized many times and only one of them being a signature field would be ok, if that is possible can all those appearances lead to the same signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow me to copy a sentence and a note from ISO-32000-2. This document isn't available yet because it will only be released in 2016. However, it is very clear on the subject of this question:

[image]

This has always been true, however: it was only documented in documentation proprietary to Adobe. Starting with PDF 2.0, it will be normative.

In short: you are asking for something that is in violation with the PDF specification.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Thank you very much for saving me from getting into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you may have one signature field and one corresponding widget annotation and also put images or other objects representing this signature in all other places.

Comment: If the document had been signed before, filling in an existing or even new signature field may be allowed but adding *images or other objects representing this signature* may not.